# What is the intution between point estimation of model parameters in statistics?

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, estimation

I am reading a topic about point estimation of model parameters. I understood it as follows:

> We have "observed" a sample $X_1,...X_n$ where we know it's distribution, i.e. the sample is identically distributed w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_\theta$ where $\theta\in \Theta$ is a model parameter (not necessarily one dimensional). For example we can have that $X_1,...X_n\stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where $\mu$ is unknown. Then in general we want to find a best approximation for $\theta$, or in our example for $\mu$. Here graphically it would mean that we want to find the center of the density function of $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, i.e. is it moved to the left or to the right. There are several ways to do this for example one is the maximum likelihood estimator, then in our example we would get $\hat \mu:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ which is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\mu$. But as we see $\hat \mu$ is a random variable, not a number.

Our prof. then told us that if we take $\omega \in \Omega$ and look at $\hat \mu(\omega)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)$ then we get a number which is called an estimate of $\mu$. But now I have the following questions:

1. I don't see is what does this do graphically, i.e. what happens graphically if I fix $\omega$?
2. if I fix different $\omega$'s then I would get different estimates, but isn't this a problem I mean how do I then know that the best one is?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The estimator is $\hat\mu$ *qua* function of $\Omega.$  The value $\hat\mu(\omega)$ is called an *estimate.*

Comment: @whuber what does qua mean?

Comment: Google it -- the first hit tells you.

Comment: @whuber ah okey I see but how can a function graphically approximate a value $\mu$? I'm a bit confused since I have $\hat \mu$ a function and $\mu$ a real value

Comment: It sounds like you might appreciate a less abstract definition.  [Searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=estimator+definition) will turn some up.

Comment: @whuber no I mean I like the thefinition but I'm a bit lost graphically because I want to find an approximation for a real value and I get a function how does this get in touch graphically?

Comment: You really need to learn some other characterizations and definitions of estimators, then, because this one isn't yet meaningful for you.

Comment: okey thanks for your help

Comment: Thank you for sharing what is difficult about "statistics speak". I find it in turn difficult to understand what you mean by "graphically" - do you mean the graph of a function where $\omega$ is on the $x$-axis and $\hat{\mu}(\omega)$ on the y-axis? 
When we talk about a function, we often understand this in a more abstract, general sense. It is difficult to explain such fundamental notions in a forum - hope you have some real people around you to discuss how all this should be understood :-)